# rails3 sort where clause issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sorting, where-clause

I followed a tutorial on rails3 sorting, not sure which one, and i got it working. I have a table, and depending on the button pushed, I wanted to be able to sort on one of the columns.

Here is an example of the buttons:
<%= link_to "Time", :sort => "transit_time" %>

The column looks like this:
<%= result.transit_time%>
(multiple times obviously)

In the controller, I originally did:

@results = Result.order(params[:sort])

And this worked.

However, now I have added a where clause to be able to query more specifically, so my query looks like this:

@results = Result.where("(NOT(train) OR :traincheckbox)AND  . . . :end_location => params[:end_location]}).order(params[:sort])

THIS NO LONGER WORKS. The reason is because when I click the button, it reloads the page, and eliminates all the query string. When I first load the page the query string looks like this:
"http://localhost:3000/results?utf8=%E2%9C%93&start_address=24+Grosvenor+Square&start_l . . .etc."
and once I push one of the sort buttons it turns to this:
http://localhost:3000/results?sort=escore

All my results disappear because there is nothing in the query string, nothing to be passed into the WHERE clause.

ANY IDEA HOW TO KEEP THOSE PARAMS PRESENT?

Sorry that is long, but I'm a relative beginner at rails and I need help.

Thanks!

Comment: Please format your code by using four space indenting or backticks (`) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would highly recommend you use the [MetaWhere and MetaSearch Gem](http://railscasts.com/episodes/251-metawhere-metasearch)

One way you can keep the variables present in your next screen is to store them in hidden fields (of a form), then when you click sort, pass those hidden fields over to form your query.

Hope this helps!